# Double-column for Question/Answer Format?

Tags: formatting, questionnaire

Wanted output

[image]

Data

```
What is your name?  Ka jus sauc?
How old are you? Cik jums ir gadu? 
When were you born?  Kad jus esat dzimi? 
What do you work with? Ar ko jus stradajat?
```

I could use Pandoc/markdown logical tables but I would like to do this directly in LaTeX. 
I can add a separator between the English and Latvian version.

### Bigger data

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
Penicillin

Amoksilav 

Cephasporin 1st gen

Cephalosporin 2nd gen
\switchcolumn
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day,
Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.

Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.

cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day,
cefradine 500 mg/2/day. 

cefaclor 250 mg/3/day, 
cefonicid 500 mg/day. 
\end{paracol}
```

which gives the following output. 
This input also gives the following input without extra empty lines, which is strange:

```
\begin{paracol}{2}
-- same as above --
\switchcolumn
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day, Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.

Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.

cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day, cefradine 500 mg/2/day. 

cefaclor 250 mg/3/day, cefonicid 500 mg/day. 
\end{paracol}
```

Output:

[image]

where I would like that the left-column adjusts with the right one such that the materials are on the corresponding lines.

How can you get the double-column wanted output?

Comment: Shouldn't it read `When where you born?`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer »When where«? :p

Comment: `\newcommand\question[1]{\makebox[.5\textwidth][l]{#1}}
\noindent\question{What is your name?}
\question{Ka jus sauc?}
\question{How old are you?}
\question{Cik jums ir gadu?}`

Comment: @clemens: Ok, I corrected only one error :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a `paracol` and `parallel` version of parallel typesetting.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{parallel}
\usepackage{paracol}

\begin{document}

\begin{paracol}{2}
What is your name?     

How old are you?       

When where you borned? 

What do you work with? 
\switchcolumn
 Ka jus sauc?

 Cik jums ir gadu? 

 Kad jus esat dzimi? 

 Ar ko jus stradajat? 
\end{paracol}

\fbox{Now with parallel package:}

\begin{Parallel}{0.4\textwidth}{0.4\textwidth}
\ParallelLText{%
What is your name?     

How old are you?       

When where you borned? 

What do you work with? 
}

\ParallelRText{%
 Ka jus sauc?

 Cik jums ir gadu? 

 Kad jus esat dzimi? 

 Ar ko jus stradajat? 
}

\end{Parallel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I added a challenge with bigger data. I noticed that the left-column is not adjusting with the right column.

Comment: @Masi: You're changed the question too!

Comment: I also made a variant of input without those empty lines but still there is the unalignmnent of columns, just because of too much content in the cells. I would be get both sides aligned.

Comment: I extended this thread to consider the dynamics of paracol application here http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/270704/13173

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tabular` environnement:

```
\begin{tabular}{ll}
What is your name? &  Ka jus sauc? \\
How old are you? & Cik jums ir gadu? \\
When where you borned? &  Kad jus esat dzimi? \\ 
What do you work with? & Ar ko jus stradajat? \\
\end{tabular}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[latvian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
What is your name? &  Ka jus sauc? \\
How old are you? & Cik jums ir gadu? \\
When where you borned? &  Kad jus esat dzimi? \\ 
What do you work with? & Ar ko jus stradajat? \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a macro version for the job:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}

\newcommand{\qa}[2]{%
  \begin{paracol}{2}
  \noindent
  #1
  \switchcolumn
  \noindent
  #2
  \end{paracol}
  }
\begin{document}

\qa{What is your name? How old are you? How old are you? How old are you?}{Ka jus sauc?}

\qa{How old are you?}{Cik jums ir gadu?}

\qa{When where you borned?}{Kad jus esat dzimi?}

\qa{What do you work with?}{Ar ko jus stradajat?}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This could be expanded such a way that you have all your Latvian questions inside the first brackets with some separator between sentences, and then English sentences inside the other brackets.

Comment: @Masi: That will not align the question with its answer if either question or answer is spanning more than two lines. See Christian's answer and use a long question/answer there.