# How to have list items without initial space?

Tags: spacing, lists, enumerate

Code mimicked from [Double-column for Question/Answer Format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/269230/13173) but with longer inputs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ī}{i\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ā}{a\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ē}{e\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ū}{u\char\string"0304 }

\begin{document}


\section{Latvian Practice}
\begin{paracol}{2}
What operations have you had before the last operation? 

What are your old diagnoses/diseases? \uline{Tuberculosis}, \uline{hepatitis}, \uline{metabolic syndrome}, diabetes? 

Have you had endoscopy?
\switchcolumn
Kādas operācijas jums bija pirms pēdējās operācijas?

Kādas ir jūsu vecās diagnozes / slimības? \uline{Tuberkuloze}, \uline{hepatīts}, \uline{metaboliskais sindroms}, diabēts?

Vai jums bija endoskopija?
\end{paracol} 

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

where challenges

- at second item and onward, a small space before the line; I do not want to this. **How to get this rid of this little space before new item?**
- The right-column is interfering the left-column. I do not want this. **How can you stop auto-adjust of left-column in the expense of the right-column?** At the end, better example with more data about the challenge.

Illustrating the second point better with the output:

[image]

where no messing up of text but autoadjust of the left-column with the right-column at the line 2.

---

I think the initial space at the beginning of lines can the source of the problems. 
**How can you have lines without the initial space?**

Comment: For removing indentation use `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}˛`., however you have problem with hyphenation of words "syndrome", "sindroms" etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` I remove indentation of sentences in `parcol` environment and manually add hyphenation possibilities to words syndrome and sindroms. After this changes of your MWE I obtain the following result:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{paracol}
    \usepackage{ulem}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{ī}{i\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ā}{a\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ē}{e\char\string"0304 }
\newunicodechar{ū}{u\char\string"0304 }

    \begin{document}
\section{Latvian Practice}
\begin{paracol}{2}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
What operations have you had before the last operation?

What are your old diagnoses/diseases? 
\uline{Tuberculosis}, \uline{hepatitis}, \uline{metabolic syn\-drome}, diabetes?

Have you had endoscopy?
\switchcolumn
Kādas operācijas jums bija pirms pēdējās operācijas?

Kādas ir jūsu vecās diagnozes/slimības? \uline{Tuberkuloze}, \uline{hepatīts}, \uline{metaboliskais sin\-droms}, diabēts?

Vai jums bija endoskopija?
\end{paracol}
    \end{document}
```

If you like to have larger vertical distance between paragraphs (sentences), then add `\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}`. Instead `1ex` you can select other distance according to your taste.

Comment: Great! Looks much better! Thank you! Any way to make this setting a general rule for document?

Comment: @Masi, yes, move `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}` (and `\setlength{\parskip}{1ex}`) in document preamble. For hyphenation you can form file width hyphenated word, which are not considered in hyphenation pattern (it should be included in your LaTeX installation) or do this manually (if in question is only few words),