# Adjusted Double-column for Question/Answer Format?

Tags: formatting, questionnaire

This thread is a continua of this [Double-column for Question/Answer Format?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269228/13173) but with focus on the dynamics between the two columns.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\begin{document}
\begin{paracol}{2}
Penicillin

Amoksilav

Cephasporin 1st gen

Cephalosporin 2nd gen
\switchcolumn
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day,
Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.

Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.

cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day,
cefradine 500 mg/2/day.

cefaclor 250 mg/3/day,
cefonicid 500
\end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

But I want:

- Penicillin on the same line as Benzyl...
- Amoksilav on the same line as Amoxilav ...
- Cephalosporin 1st on the same line as cefacetrile ...
- Cephalosporin 2nd gen on the same line as cefaclor ...

### touhami's output

[image]

but code includes many `switchcolumns`:

```
\begin{paracol}{2} Penicillin \switchcolumn Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day, Oxacillin 1 g/2/day. \switchcolumn* Amoksilav \switchcolumn Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day. \switchcolumn* Cephasporin 1st gen \switchcolumn cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day, cefradine 500 mg/2/day. \switchcolumn* Cephalosporin 2nd gen \switchcolumn cefaclor 250 mg/3/day, cefonicid 500 \end{paracol}
```

---

How can you keep the corresponding lines of two columns matching each other? 
I do not like to use table format. 
I like a lot the syntax of this paracol.

Comment: try `\begin{paracol}{2}
Penicillin
\switchcolumn
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day,
Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.
\switchcolumn*
Amoksilav
\switchcolumn
Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.
\switchcolumn*
Cephasporin 1st gen
\switchcolumn
cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day,
cefradine 500 mg/2/day.
\switchcolumn*
Cephalosporin 2nd gen
\switchcolumn
cefaclor 250 mg/3/day,
cefonicid 500
\end{paracol}`

Comment: Nice output! However, I am interested in if you could do this without some many semantic commands.

Comment: Isn't a `tabular` much better suited here?

Comment: Maybe. I am still thinking `paracol` because I like its initial syntax and I think it should be possible to have the 2nd output with some minimum semantics.

Comment: You need to set anchors for the package to know what sticks together. `paracol` is intended for paragraphs of text, not for lists.

Answer (score 2):

The question title mentions Question-Answer stuff, the picture shows a regular list. A list is ususally done using a list environment, this time using `labeling` provided by KOMA-script.

Sometimes, a `tabular` environment can be used to do list-like stuff as well.

[image: masiQA]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{labeling}{Cephalosporin 2nd gen}
\item [Penicillin]
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day,\\
Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.
\item [Amoksilav]
Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.
\item [Cephasporin 1st gen]
cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day,\\
cefradine 500 mg/2/day.
\item [Cephalosporin 2nd gen]
cefaclor 250 mg/3/day,\\
cefonicid 500
\end{labeling}
\bigbreak\noindent\rule{.5\textwidth}{.4pt}\bigbreak
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lX}
Penicillin &
Benzylpenicillin 600 mg/2/day,
\newline Oxacillin 1 g/2/day.  \\
Amoksilav & Amoxilav 500 mg/2/day.  \\
Cephasporin 1st gen &
cefacetrile 500 mg/2/day,
\newline cefradine 500 mg/2/day.  \\
Cephalosporin 2nd gen & cefaclor 250 mg/3/day,
\newline cefonicid 500
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I actually like the labelling environment. Little better. It is easy to read such semantics. So things keep together. Thank you!

Comment: @Masi I am not really sure if you mean the same with *semantics* as the rest of us.